# How does IIFE works when I assign an IIFE to a variable?

Tags: javascript, iife

I was confused with this following code in javascript.

```
var x=(function(){
  var customObject = function(){};

  customObject.prototype.sayHello=function(){
  alert("hello");
  };

  return customObject;
})();

//var y=new x();// If I uncomment this line and comment the next line "var 
//y=x;" the code works 
var y=x;
y.sayHello();
```

This code doesn't say hello but it does when I remove the comment. I read that IIFE executed immediately after it is defined. So, it should assign the customObject to x directly.

My question is that why I need to create a new instance of x to say hello. It is not clear to me how IIFE is working here.

Please help me to understand this concept. Thank you in advance :-) .

Comment: The IIFE returns `customObject`. `customObject` is a constructor function that needs to be called with `new` to create a new instance of it. The IIFE won't do that for you. *"How does IIFE works when I assign an IIFE to a variable?"* You are not assigning the IIFE to a variable. You are assigning the *return value* of the IIFE to a variable. An IIFE is just a function call. There is nothing special about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct that the `customObject` is assigned to `x`.  But `customObject` (and therefore `x`) does not have a `sayHello` property.  It has a `prototype` property, and *that* has a `sayHello` property.

When you do `y=x` and then `y.sayHello()`, you're trying to call `customObject.sayHello`, which doesn't exist.

When you do `y=new x()`, you create an object whose prototype is the `customObject.prototype` object.  Then, when you call `y.sayHello()`, the `sayHello` function is found via the prototype chain.

This isn't really related to your use of an IIFE.  You'd get the same result if you just wrote:

```
var x = function() {}
x.prototype.sayHello = function() {
  alert("hello");
}
```

instead of the IIFE.

Comment: Thank you so much for this clarification.It really helps.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got your confusion here.

**First**, IIFE is doing its job correctly here. It executes and returns `customObject` to variable `x`

This is what it is supposed to do.

Now coming to your actual question, ***why I need to create a new instance of x to say hello***?

You may have read, all `classes(functions)` have a `prototype` and all `variables` have `__proto__` property.

Anything set on a prototype is accessible to instances of that constructor.

**For ex:**

`var myName = "apl"; // a simple string`

`console.log(myName.toUpperCase())  // outputs: APL`

How do you think we were able to call `toUpperCase()` on our variable name?

We could, since `typeof(myName )` turns out to be `string`. So `myName` would be able to call any properties/methods which are set on `String.prototype`.

In short, `__proto__` property on `myName` should be set to String's `prototype`

i.e `myName.__proto__ === String.prototype` // true since myName is an instance of String

Hence, in your case, you need `y` to be an instance of `x`. Only then you would be able to access methods set on `x` prototype which in turn is `customObject.prototype`

Comment: Thank you so much for this informative answer. It clears my confusion :-)